# javascript trouble alert specific time

Tags: javascript, datetime

I get the clock working fine, counting current time, but i want an alert box to pop up when it is a specific time... Any help here?

```
window.onload = oppstart;


function oppstart() {

    var tid = new Date();

    var timer = tid.getHours();

    var minutter = tid.getMinutes();

    var sekunder = tid.getSeconds();

    document.getElementById("tiden").innerHTML = tid.getHours() + ":" + tid.getMinutes() + ":" +  tid.getSeconds();

    setTimeout(oppstart,1000);

    if(tid == 13.28){
        alert("Nå er klokka 13.28!!")
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: `tid` is probably not equal to `13.28`.

Comment: `tid == 13.28` would never be true, because the Date's string format is different.

Answer (score 0):

`tid` is an object of class `Date`. It is not something you should compare with a number expecting it to be `hour.minutes`.

Change:

```
if(tid == 13.28){
```

to:

```
if (timer == 13 && minutter == 28) {
```

Comment: True, @Xufox, I will rephrase that.